# Find the angles between the sides and a diagonal of a $1 \times 2$ rectangle.

Tags: linear-algebra

I know the correct answers and the way they are worked out.

Initially, I thought like this(wrongly): let $u$ be the side of length $1$. The diagonal is of length $\sqrt 5$. Name it $w$. Then the angle between $u$ and $w$ is given by $\cos x = \frac {u \cdot w} { \|u|\| \|w\|}$. The denominator is $\sqrt 5$. For the numerator we need the vectors $u$ and $w$ so I tried to use Pythagoras' to extract components of $u$ and $w$. I thought this way of doing things would give me the angle between $u$ and $w$. I guess somewhere along the way my thinking must've gone all kinds of wrong. Please, help me see it.

Comment: Locate one corner at the origin, with the sides along the positive axes (let's say the short side is along the $x$-axis.  Then $\vec u=(1,0)$ and $\vec w =(1,2))$.

Comment: Originally I decomposed $u$ as $(1, 1)$ and $w$ as $(1, 2)$ which is wrong because the longer side must be $(0, 2)$, correct?

Comment: $(1, 1)$ doesn't give right length for $u$. Very stupid mistake.

Comment: You are correct, the long side that touches the origin cn be thought of as the vector $(2,0)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you might be overthinking this. If you draw a diagonal, you divide the rectangle into two equal right triangles. You already know two of the sides of the triangle, that is the sides which aren't the hypotenuse. That is sufficient. Compute $\arctan(1/2)$ to find the desired angle.